# How do I reverse ORDER BY to give me the smallest instead of the largest?

Tags: c#, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

The below method has a command that prints out the rows of my database in the textbox. It only prints out maxDataBaseListings # of rows. However, it prints them out from oldest date to newest date. If maxDatabaseListings is 10, and my 11th entry has an newer date than my 10th entry, it won't display.

How can I reverse the ORDER BY command to show the newest dates first? This way, when the method is called, it will refresh the table with the newest date listed first.

```
public void refreshListing(TextBox inputTextBox, TextBox inputMaxDatabaseListings)
    {
        if (currentlyConnectedToADatabase)
        {
            maxDatabaseListings = returnMaxListings(inputMaxDatabaseListings.Text, numberOfDatabaseListings);
            inputTextBox.Text = "";
            cnn.Open();

            //COMMAND HERE
            command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tcn.Demo ORDER BY DateTimeOfInsertion, SomeNumber, SomeText, AnotherNumber", cnn); 


            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            theTextBox = inputTextBox;
            int i =0;
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read() && i < maxDatabaseListings)
                {
                    string printString = int.Parse(reader["SomeNumber"].ToString()) + " " + reader["SomeText"].ToString() + " " + int.Parse(reader["AnotherNumber"].ToString()) + " at " + reader["DateTimeOfInsertion"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                    theTextBox.AppendText(printString);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
            }

            reader.Close();
            cnn.Close();
        } 
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You must first connect to a database!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: use descending order: `ORDER BY [FieldName] DESC`

Comment: wow, that was a lot easier than I thought, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORDER BY column_1 DESC, column_2, column_n
```

Comment: your welcome, there will always be a first time for everyone